# page scroll to absolute top view child height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a div products with lots of data. and a div with signup form using absolute position and z-index:2 and a button to display and hide that signup form . its show at the top when user click on signup. But i want my page to scroll till the height of signup form. but its scroll till the whole body i.e, also shows last products. i have created snippet with my code example. here i want to scroll pagetill yellow background only.  I want to do this using Pure CSS or hardly pure java script and can't use J Query.

```css
#signup
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:10%;
z-index:2;
background-color:#ffff00;
width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Product">
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  </div>
<div id="signup">
  <h1>Login</h1>
<input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
   <input type="text"/><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly the problem but if I do I don't think this is possible with CSS only - you could use a hashtag to obtain an anchor in the page, but otherwise you might need to use jquery or experimental `scrollIntoView` function for pure js

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```css
#signup
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:10%;
z-index:2;
background-color:#ffff00;
width:80%;
  height: 300px;
overflow: auto;
}

body{
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

```html
<div id="Product">
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  <h1>Something Goes Here</h1>
  </div>
<div id="signup">
  <h1>Login</h1>
<input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
  <input type="text"/><br><br>
   <input type="text"/><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: its working fine once i click on signup button. but if i close it body is also stop scrolling plus not working on mobile phone

Comment: can you give me your JSfiddle file or something to check that bug

Comment: Try resize this height. Scroll visible if height of content higher over it's div

Comment: i told you "once i click on signup button. but if i close it body is also stop scrolling" for this i have to switch between body overflow hidden and scroll